# Restkit [operation waitUntilFinished] not working

Tags: restkit, nsoperation, restkit-0.24.x

I'm using reskit inside my cocoapods library I have an example library where I reference my own library to make the call, so when I make the call from IOS example code I get empty result. This is my code.

```
RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[responseDescriptor]];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation                  *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {
    device = result.firstObject;
} failure:nil];

[operation start];
[operation waitUntilFinished];

return device;
```

Answer (score 0):

Operation completion blocks are called after the operation is complete, but I think also after the operation has finished, which is what you wait for. You can check this with log statements. As such the `device` hasn't been set.

You don't actually need the block, just remove it and access the `mappingResult` directly after you're told the operation is complete.